# how to copy dir from remote host to docker image

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to build a docker image, I have dockerfile with all necessary commands. but in my build steps I need to copy one dir from remote host to docker image. But if I put scp command into dockerfile, i'll have to provide password also into dockerfile, which I dont have to.

Anyone has some better solution to do this. any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say there are at least options for dealing with that:

**Option 1:**
If you can execute `scp` before running `docker build` this may turn out to be the easiest option:

1. Run `scp -r somewhere:remote_dir ./local_dir`
2. Add `COPY ./local_dir some_path` to your Dockerfile
3. Run `docker build`

**Option 2:** If you have to execute `scp` during the build:

1. Start some key-value store such as [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) before the build
2. Place a correct SSH key (it cannot be password-protected) temporarily in the key-value store
3. Within a single `RUN` command (to avoid leaving secrets inside the image):

   - retrieve the SSH key from the key-value store;
   - put it in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or start an `ssh-agent` and add it;
   - retrieve the directory with `scp`
   - remove the SSH key
4. Remove the key from the key-value store

The second option is a bit convoluted, so it may be worth creating a wrapper script that retrieves the required secrets, runs any command, and removes the secrets.

Comment: I'll add option #3.    Tar/gzip them up and make them accessible via HTTP.   ADD can accept a remote destination and will auto-unzip.

Comment: @user2105103 This would indeed be easier if you don't require authentication, or if pass or hardcode an unguessable URL. It's also worth noting that the usage of `ADD` is discouraged for similar use cases: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/add-or-copy

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a directory into a (even running) container at *post build time*

1. On remote machine: Copy from remote host to docker host with

   `scp -r /your/dir/ <user-at-docker-host>@<docker-host>:/some/remote/directory`
2. On docker machine: Copy from docker host into docker container

   `docker cp /some/remote/directory <container-name>:/some/dir/within/docker/`

Of course you can do step 1 also from your docker machine if you prefere that by simply adapting the *source* and *target* of the *scp* command.